# Вылет при вводе неподдерживаемой информации в модуль wikipedia (Python3.8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, mediawiki

Пишу макет для работы с википедией на python3 и когда пользователь вводит информацию, которой на википедии нет или просто набор символов, то программа вылетает (файл .py закрывается), можно ли как-то обойти эту проблему.
Используются python3.8 и модуль: wikipedia.
Код:

```
import wikipedia

Input = input("Запрос?")
Searcher = "Start"

wikipedia.set_lang("RU")
Searcher = wikipedia.summary(Input)
print(Searcher)
```

Traceback
[image: Traceback]

(Планирую использовать это в своём боте вк, через vk_api).

Comment: *>>файл .py закрывается* - как Вы запускаете?

Comment: Через клик, а если запускать через python file.py выводит traceback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Модуль wikipedia выбрасывает исключение, и это нормальный способ работы с ошибками - выкидывать исключение определённого типа. Ловите это исключение (через try 
except) в своём модуле там, где вызываете функции из модуля wikipedia и делайте что вам нужно в этом случае делать, например, печатайте информацию об ошибке. Пример кода, где ловятся исключения любого типа:

```
import wikipedia

Input = input("Запрос?")
Searcher = "Start"

wikipedia.set_lang("RU")

try:
  Searcher = wikipedia.summary(Input)
  print(Searcher)
except:
  print('Статья не найдена!')
```